# "began" vs "begun"

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference, and when should I use which?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*began* = simple past form of the verb

*begun* = past participle form of the verb

> - I began to run.
> - I have begun to run.

Comment: Those are particularly appropriate examples, as "run" and "ran" are used in the same way.